# Update mysql data on textarea click off

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have this code below:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from controldata where field = :field ");
$stmt->execute(array(':field' => 'notice_board'));
$result = $stmt->fetch();
?>
<textarea id="notice_board_textarea" data-id="notice_board" rows="8"><?php echo stripslashes(strip_tags($result["value"])); ?></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#notice_board_textarea').on('blur', function () { // don't forget # to select by id
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // Get the id-data-attribute
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dashboard.php?update_notice_board=yes",
        data: {
            notes: val, // value of the textarea we are hooking the blur-event to
            itemId: id // Id of the item stored on the data-id
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

which selects data from a MySQL database and shows it in a textarea

then then JS code updates it by POSTing the data to another page but without refreshing the page or clicking a save/submit button

on dashboard.php i have this code:

```
if($_GET["update_notice_board"] == 'yes')
{
    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("UPDATE controldata SET value = :value WHERE field = :field ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':value' => $_POST["notes"], ':field' => 'notice_board'));
}
```

but its not updating the data

am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: $_GET is likely empty because you do a post. Try adding the update_notice_board:"yes" to the data object in your ajax call and look in $_POST in the server instead.

Comment: Is the data not updated in your database? Are you sure the dashboard.php script executes? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: the URL is dashboard.php?update_notice_board=yes so thats where the get is from and then i POST the data from the form

Comment: @donnywals nope - no errors at all

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

Based on what's written in the comments below, my guess is, it is a server side issue, beyond what is shared here. Perhaps dashboard.php is part of a framework that empty the super globals or perhaps the request is not going directly to dashboard.php

**Old suggestions**:

<strike>When you use `type: "POST"` you wont find the parameters in the `$_GET` variable.</strike> (U: Actually you probably would find it in `$_GET`, but in my opinion it's cleaner to put all vars in either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, although there may be semantic arguments to prefer the splitting).

Add your parameter to the `data` object of your ajax call and read it from the `$_POST` variable instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dashboard.php",
    data: {
        notes: val, // value of the textarea we are hooking the blur-event to
        itemId: id, // Id of the item stored on the data-id
        update_notice_board:"yes"
    },
    success: function(reply) {
        alert(reply);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown ) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

and

```
if($_POST["update_notice_board"] == 'yes')
```

(You may also look in `$_REQUEST` if you don't care whether the request is get or post.)

Compare the documentation entries:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Working client-side example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kLUyx/

Comment: i have updaated to use your code you provided but its still not updating at all

Comment: Does it work without the if-check? If yes, what is returned by `var_dump($_REQUEST);` ? (You may see the response to ajax requests in a proper debuggers network tab)

Comment: If yes, what is returned by var_dump($_REQUEST); ? (You may see the response to ajax requests in a proper debugger's network tab. The built in tools in the newest versions of firefox, chrome and ie all have such a function.)

Comment: ok check here - http://pastebin.com/uMBnePMY where i have put domain.com that is my domain name

Comment: I added a missing `,` after itemId: id in my example. The dump you posted does not look like it comes from the ajax-request, since it has neither of the three parameters.

Comment: this is still not updating the database

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the client side is right. My guess is the server side, but I can't spot the error from the code you have posted. I tried adding callback functions to the ajax call that may help you debug the server side code a bit. Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate the client-side part works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLUyx/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:

```
if ($_POST["update_notice_board"] == 'yes') {
```

Right:

```
if ($_GET['update_notice_board'] == 'yes') {
```

When you append something straight to the URL, it is ALWAYS GET:

```
url: "dashboard.php?update_notice_board=yes",
```